# Why is Docker downloading so much when installing NodeJS?

Tags: docker, node.js

I have a simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:4.2.2
EXPOSE 8000
```

When I run `docker build -t myapp .`, it shows the size of downloaded stuff:

[image: NodeJS installing with Docker]

Which seems larger than 200Mb though NodeJS itself is not larger than 30Mb. What are other things that are being downloaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker will install a lot more than the application itself because Docker is a container solution and not a package manager like apt or rpm. Docker should be compared to whole-system virtualization like Xen, VMWare or VirtualBox. From the Docker documentation:

> Docker allows you to package an application with all of its dependencies into a standardized unit for software development.
>
> Docker containers wrap up a piece of software in a complete filesystem that contains everything it needs to run: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries – anything you can install on a server. This guarantees that it will always run the same, regardless of the environment it is running in.
> [source](https://www.docker.com/what-docker)

`FROM node:4.2.2` for example will deploy a docker container based on Debian wheezy which gives you a basic Debian environment. And to give you that Docker needs to install a bit more than just nodejs.

If you want to know what exactlly is installed you need to look up the Dockerfiles you included in your Dockerfile. In this case `node:4.2.2`. Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/node). You can see there that another Dockercontainer is included `buildpack-deps:wheezy`. If you look into that [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/wheezy/Dockerfile) you can see that these packages are installed:

```
    autoconf \
    automake \
    bzip2 \
    file \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    imagemagick \
    libbz2-dev \
    libc6-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libevent-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libgeoip-dev \
    libglib2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    libmagickcore-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmysqlclient-dev \
    libncurses-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libtool \
    libwebp-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libyaml-dev \
    make \
    patch \
    xz-utils \
    zlib1g-dev \
```

Comment: "because Docker is a container solution" doesn't really explain much; "because the container contains all dependencies" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Each container image is built in layers; if you run

```
docker history myapp
```

you will see the size of each layer; as the other answer says the bulk of it is probably in the `debian` layer.